# Bivariate Distribution with Uniform Marginals is Bound to be Uniform?

Tags: probability, joint-distribution, uniform-distribution, copula

If $X\sim U , Y\sim U$ , and $X,Y$ may be non-independent. Can we say the joint distribution of $X,Y$ is uniform?

Comment: A term that might interest you is *copula*.

Comment: Consider the case $X=Y.$

Comment: See [Is there a bivariate β
distribution I can fit to my data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315865/is-there-a-bivariate-beta-distribution-i-can-fit-to-my-data/535945#535945) for examples! (choose the parameters so that the marginals are uniform).

Comment: Consider a chessboard, and imagine the probability is uniform on the white squares

Answer (score 6):

No, the joint distribution is not necessarily uniform.

Consider $X$ and $Y$ with a joint pdf

$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
2, \text{if } x \in (0,0.5), y \in (0,0.5)\\
2, \text{if }x \in (0.5,1), y \in (0.5,1) \\
0, \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Then both $X$ and $Y$ have marginal $U(0,1)$ distributions, but the joint distribution is not uniform.

Comment: +1 [I put together a visualization of your density.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE8kZ.png) `set.seed(2021); N <- 1000; x1 <- runif(N, 0, 0.5); x2 <- runif(N, 0.5, 1); y1 <- runif(N, 0, 0.5); y2 <- runif(N, 0.5, 1); x <- c(x1, x2); y <- c(y1, y2); par(mfrow = c(3, 1)); plot(x, y); plot(x, ecdf(x)(x), main = "CDF of x"); abline(a = 0, b = 1); plot(y, ecdf(y)(y), main = "CDF of y"); abline(a = 0, b = 1)`

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $X\sim Unif(0,1)$ and $Y\sim Unif(0,X)$, then the joint distribution will be

$$f(X,Y)=f(Y|X)f(X)=\frac{1}{x}, \ \ \ 0\leq y \leq x\leq 1$$

If I'm not mistaken a uniform distribution gives the same importance to the whole domain of $(X,Y)$, whereas in the case displayed the importance given depends on the sampled $X$.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that although $Y|X \sim Unif(0,X)$, the marginal distribution of $Y$ is not uniform.

Comment: If the parameter of interval is a random variable, it is a uniform disturbution? In fact, many definitions do not clearly indicate this problem. Anyway, copula is a better interpretation to solve this question for me.